# Use a dynamic funtion to build a list of radio buttons using an enum as the value

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

Im trying to create lists of radio buttons with a function. This is many different lists using different enum types.

Here is what I have so far. The problem is the `groupValue` loses its pointer. So when a radio button is tapped the pointer passed into the function does not reflect changes.

```
List<Widget> _buildRadioButtonList(List<dynamic> values, groupValue) {
  List<Widget> radioButtons = [];
  for (var value in values) {
    radioButtons.add(
      RadioListTile<dynamic>(
        title: Text(GF.enumToString(value)),
        value: value,
        groupValue: groupValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setRadio(value, groupValue);
          setState(() {
            groupValue = value;
          });
        },
        selected: groupValue == value,
      ),
    );
  }

  return radioButtons;
}
```

This is how the function is used

```
enum IsFinished { Positive, Negative, Unknown }

IsFinished _isFinishedGroupValue = isFinished.unknown;

Widget build(BuildContext context) { 

return Column(
  children: _buildRadioButtonList(IsFinished.values, _isFinishedGroupValue)

}
```

NOTE `GF.enumToString(value)` just gets a string from an enum to be used as a label

```
static String enumToString(value) {
  return value.toString().split('.').last;
}
```

Inside `setState` the `groupValue` gets changed on tap but the original reference passed in `_isFinishedGroupValue` remains unchanged. How do I get this working as I intend without having to write a new build function for every enum?

Comment: Dart uses pass by value, so the value you assign to groupValue is only visible inside that method. To propagate the value out, you can pass in a method that you call with the new value. That method can then set values within its scope.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice. This is what I will do.

Comment: @Shannon It will be very useful if u can post the answer with the required code changes.please...

Comment: @RichardHeap So u mean that, to pass the groupValue using a call back function and then update the _isFinishedGroupValue inside where the callback function is been received???

Answer (score 0):

As @Richard Heap commented, below will be the way to do this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '...../globals.dart';

class CustomRadioView extends StatefulWidget {
const CustomRadioView(
    {Key? key,
        required this.values,
        required this.groupValue,
        required this.onItemSelected})
    : super(key: key);
final List<dynamic> values;
final dynamic groupValue;
final dynamic Function(dynamic selectedValue) onItemSelected;
@override
_CustomRadioViewState createState() => _CustomRadioViewState();
}

class _CustomRadioViewState extends State<CustomRadioView> {
late dynamic groupNewValue;

@override
void initState() {
    groupNewValue = widget.groupValue;
    super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: buildList(context),
    ),
    );
}

buildList(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> radioButtons = [];
    for (var value in widget.values) {
    radioButtons.add(
        Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: RadioListTile<dynamic>(
            title: Text(Globals.enumToString(value),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,),),
            value: value,
            groupValue: groupNewValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
                groupNewValue = value;
            });
            widget.onItemSelected(value);
            },
            selected: groupNewValue == value,
        ),
        ),
    );
    }

    return radioButtons;
}

}


class Globals {
    static String enumToString(value) {
    return value.toString().split('.').last;
}
}
```

And use this widget anywhere you want as below :

```
enum IsFinished { Positive, Negative, Unknown }

IsFinished _isFinishedGroupValue = isFinished.unknown;

Widget build(BuildContext context) { 

return Container(
  child: CustomRadioView(
        values: IsFinished.values,
        groupValue: _isFinishedGroupValue,
        onItemSelected: (value) {
            _isFinishedGroupValue = value;
        },
    ),
  );

}
```

You can use any enum type on the above code.

UPDATE :

With Dart 2.17 and above:

```
// Dart 2.17 can convert enum value to any value
// and you do not need to create an enumToString(value)/extension to put a value name to the radio button view.
enum IsFinished {
Positive('Positive'),
Negative('Negative'),
Unknown('Unknown'),
DataLoading('Data Loading');

const IsFinished(this.label);

// View in the user interface "title: Text(value.label)"
final String label;
}
```

And inside RadioListTile use :

```
title: Text(value.label,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,),),
```